# Rewriting a T-SQL query that delete more than 30k rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I want to delete as many as 30k rows in a table in TSQL, 
I can't use

`delete from myTable where Id in (1,2,3,...,30k)`

because the number of IDs in the IN clause is too big, according to this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288095

But how can I rewrite my query to delete the rows using a temporary table and table joins?

EDIT: The IDs are not in order. They are picked by certain logic so they are just some arbitrary IDs in myTable.

Comment: Can you give more information about the data?

Comment: Are the ids actually contiguous? Do you want to do all 30K in one batch? What version are you on? That KB article is for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Temp table isn't going to help you, you would need to insert all the id's you want to delete first, can you not do it using a between, or some sort of where criteria?

Comment: What is the logic by which the code that builds the In clause of 30K items ids?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
INTO #tmpIDs
FROM tbl_IDTable
WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 30000

DELETE MYTABLE 
FROM MYTABLE t
INNER JOIN #tmpIDs d ON d.id = t.id

DROP TABLE #tmpIDs
```

* IF IT IS A QUERY INSIDE ANOTHER QUERY *********

```
 DELETE MYTABLE 
    FROM MYTABLE t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID
                FROM MYTABLE
                WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 30000) d d.id = t.id
```

Comment: Couldn't you just write that as `DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 30000`?

Comment: @Phill, your right if he wants to get all the ID's between 1 to 3000, if he wants to do any other tests or get a list of ID's from another table he can use the above for all scenarios.

Comment: @Robbie - Fair call, I think we need more information from the OP tho to give him the best answer.

Comment: the ids are not in order. They are just some rows picked by certain logic.

Comment: @newguy - Can you explain how you're picking the rows then in your question.

Comment: The logic behind this is complex, they are those in the database but not in an imported file and also need to meet some other requirements. I am in a process of building this query into an application. I don't want to get into more details of how the IDs are generated. For the time being let's focus on how to delete them successfully.

Comment: @newguy - I'm talking about the logic which defines what is to be deleted, so we can possibly just write a where clause into your query to delete them successfully. If you're going to be vague thats fine, it just makes it impossible to help you.

Comment: @Phill - a Non related statement = "Kiwi living in Australia, showing Australians what real work is" i think it Should be Kiwi living in Australia, showing Australians not living in Sydney what real work is"

Comment: @Robbie - Why Australians not living in Sydney? The statement is just a bit of fun tho, kiwi/aussie rivalry :)

Comment: Cause im an Australian Living in Sydney... And i know what Real work is :P

Comment: @Robbie - haha, I'm in Sydney too :) tried looking at your site but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @newguy - Been 3 years in development. Still sitting there doing nothing, blog will be up very very soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting only that specific limit, you could try something like this:

```
delete from myTable where ID = 1 or ID = 2 or ID = 3 or ID = ...
```

You may just hit a different limit then, though.

Best solution, imho is to split things into multiple queries when you generate the sql and run things in separate batches.

Comment: The query I am asking for is actually a query inside another big query. The rows are actually more than 30k, probably 50k - 60k. So splitting the queries does not seem to make it much easier.

Comment: @newguy - Can you post that query then. You probably don't need a `#temp` table at all.